# Object not following entirety of Bezier curve using array and curve modifiers

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I have had a look around and believe I have a unique problem.
Here I have a long, complex Bezier curve, the min and max radius is one and both the mesh and the curve are set to the same origin and all transforms/rotations have been applied!
When I apply the deform axis '-x', it faces the other way.

[image]

As you can see, the object does follow a portion of the curve, but I cannot extend it by choosing a long fixed count fit type as opposed to the curve fit which I have selected.

Comment: Hello could you please the object and curve (not the rest of the scene)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to use the draw feature, when only extrusions seem to extend the mesh path.
[image]